# Refator code, written in Kotlin into more functional way

Tags: generics, kotlin, functional-programming

I wonder how can I refactor this working code in Kotlin to look more functional and perhaps more elegant?

```
val validBrands = asList(*banners!!.split(",".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray())
val stores = storeCouponProducerService.getStores() //this is the list of Store object that has 3 variables.
val brandsWithDivs:MutableList<Pair<String, String>> = ArrayList()
for(store in stores){
    val brand = storeCouponProducerService.normalizeBrands(store.brand)
    if (validBrands.contains(brand)){ //perhaps ".filter" method could be used here.
        val division = store.managementDivisionNumber
        val pair = Pair(brand, division)
        brandsWithDivs.add(pair)
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [lambda expressions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions) (with an [implicit argument](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter)), [map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html), and [filter](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) to replace the loop with just three lines.

Your code should look something like this:

```
val brandsAndDivs = stores
    .filter { normalize(it.brand) in validBrands }
    .map { Pair(it.brand, it.division) }
```

Comment: Looks very elegant .. like the filter, but the division is a property of store? and brand is the normalized value? maybe i am wrong, but for me there is something missing?

Comment: I left out the specific details so the asker would have to think through the code, if only a little, rather than being able to copy it completely blindly.

Comment: It's pretty much worked, on the pair I had to call normalize again and it worked like a charm! Thanks jirassimok for replying fast!

Comment: The very nature of the question was to learn about how to rewrite already-working code in a more readable way. They weren't going to copy-paste without looking anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
val brandsWithDivs = stores.map{ it to storeCouponProducerService.normalizeBrands(store.brand)} // creates a pair of store and brand
                           .filter{ validBrands.contains(it.second) }
                           .map{ Pair(it.second, it.first.managementDivisionNumber) }
```